# Titanium Appcelerator Listview onItemLongclick alternative?

Tags: data-binding, onclick, titanium, appcelerator

> **DATABINDING**

How can I assign events like `onItemclick` to Listview items but instead of it behaving like `onClick`" I want something like "`onLongClick`" or "`onSwipe`", is there any workaround to this?

```
<ListView id="userList" defaultItemTemplate="user" onItemclick="deleteProfile"> 
        <Templates>

            <ItemTemplate bindId="user" name="user">
                <Label bindId="name" class="name"/>
            </ItemTemplate>

        </Templates>

        <ListSection id="section" dataCollection="users">
            <ListItem template="user" user:id="{id}" user:adresse="{adresse}" name:text="{author}"/>
        </ListSection>

</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ListView doesn't have `Longpress` event. You'll need to switch to `TableView` instead to get that to work.

Comment: Took for a while but i just converted it, works great, thanks!